# "Permission denied" while using flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a messenger bot using Wit.ai. For that I need a webhook. I am using ngrok, and this is just a test file but I am getting this error.

This is the error I am getting.

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 56, in <module>
    app.run(debug = True, port = 80)
  File "/home/parth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 988, in run_simple
    s.bind(server_address)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

This is the code

```
import os, sys
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def verify():
    # Webhook verification
    if request.args.get("hub.mode") == "subscribe" and request.args.get("hub.challenge"):
        if not request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == "hello":
            return "Verification token mismatch", 403
        return request.args["hub.challenge"], 200
    return "Hello world", 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, port = 80)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you test running on port 5000?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html

Comment: It worked! Thank you, I had no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're using a [Privileged Port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html).

> The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users
>   are not allowed to run servers on them.
>
> ...
>
> When you run a server as a test from a non-priviliged account, you
>   will normally test it on other ports, such as 2784, 5000, 8001 or
>   8080.

Change your port to 5000, for example, and that will fix your problem.

Comment: What if I still want to run it on a privileged port? I tried using sudo, but now I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, flash, send_file
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Comment: @xkcd do you have flask installed at system level? (`sudo pip install ...`)

Comment: No, only in the venv ... I was under the impression that doing sudo pip install was a bad idea :$

Comment: @xkcd using a privileged port is also a bad idea

Comment: Yes, I guess its essentially the same thing as sudo :) ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port number is the better solution. If you can do that, don't read this. This solution opens up routes for gaining root control of your server.

However to run on a priveleged port, you don't need to `sudo pip install`. In case you missed the first para, never do this in production or on any server within a secure environment.

That said, you can just run with sudo, from a non-root installed venv, using:

```
sudo /path/to/venv/bin/python application.py
```

or, if you don't have the `if __name__ == "__main__"` bit:

```
sudo FLASK_APP=application.py /path/to/venv/bin/flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

I pip installed with a non-root user, which is slightly safer.